# How do I traverse a collection in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I want to be able to do:

```
For Each thing In things
End For
```

CLASSIC ASP - NOT .NET!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever your [things] are need to be written outside of VBScript.

In VB6, [you can write a Custom Collection class](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_custom_collection_with_for_each.html), then you'll need to compile to an ActiveX DLL and register it on your webserver to access it.

Answer (score 13):

Something like this?

```
dim cars(2),x
cars(0)="Volvo"
cars(1)="Saab"
cars(2)="BMW"

For Each x in cars
  response.write(x & "<br />")
Next
```

See [www.w3schools.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20140305020029/http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_looping.asp).

If you want to associate keys and values [use a dictionary object](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619173138/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102898-1.shtml) instead:

```
Dim objDictionary
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
objDictionary.Add "Name", "Scott"
objDictionary.Add "Age", "20"
if objDictionary.Exists("Name") then
    ' Do something
else
    ' Do something else 
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you are going to get is using a Dictionary (as mentioned by Pacifika)

```
Dim objDictionary
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
objDictionary.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'makes the keys case insensitive'
objDictionary.Add "Name", "Scott"
objDictionary.Add "Age", "20"
```

But I loop through my dictionaries like a collection

```
For Each Entry In objDictionary
  Response.write objDictionary(Entry) & "<br />"
Next
```

You can loop through the entire dictionary this way writing out the values which would look like this:

```
Scott
20
```

You can also do this

```
For Each Entry In objDictionary
  Response.write Entry & ": " & objDictionary(Entry) & "<br />"
Next
```

Which would produce

```
 Name: Scott
 Age: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach I've used before is to use a property of the collection that returns an array, which can be iterated over.

```
Class MyCollection
    Public Property Get Items
        Items = ReturnItemsAsAnArray()
    End Property
    ...
End Class
```

Iterate like:

```
Set things = New MyCollection
For Each thing in things.Items
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As Brett said, its better to use a vb component to create collections. Dictionary objects are not very commonly used in ASP unless for specific need based applications.

Answer (score 0):

Be VERY carefully on using VB Script Dictionary Object!
Just discover this "***autovivication***" thing, native on this object: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

So, when you need to compare values, NEVER use a boolen comparison like:
`If objDic.Item("varName") <> "" Then`...
This will **automatically** add the key "`varName`" to the dictionary (if it doesn't exist, with an empty value) , in order to carry on evaluating the boolean expression.

If needed, use instead `If objDic.Exists("varName")`.

Just spend a few days knocking walls, with this Microsoft "*feature*"...
[vbscript-dictionary-object-creating-a-key-which-never-existed-but-present-in-another-object](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/906ecc76-f0c2-4823-be2a-fb5eaf8179fd/vbscript-dictionary-object-creating-a-key-which-never-existed-but-present-in-another-object)